# vuejs calling function in child component after parent function is completed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got simple button that calls two functions: in the parent and child component:

```
<btn @click.native="() => {functionParent();
$refs.childComponent.functionChild()}">Call functions<btn>
```

I know that arrow type of calling `@click` is a bad practice, but I will correct it later.

Now the problem is that `functionParent()` needs to be completed before `functionChild()` will start. But in my case `functionChild()` is running before `functionParent()` is completed - which is bad. 
How can I correct it? I want to call `functionChild()` after `functionParent()` is completed. Any ideas how to do it?

edit: 
(more details)

parent component:

```
<child-comp
:result-array="resultArray"
ref="childComponent"> 
</child-comp>

<script>
methods: {
  functionParent() {
    this.resultArray = "result"
  }
}
</script>
```

in child component:

```
<script>
props: ['resultArray'],
methods: {
   functionChild() {
      if (this.resultArray == "result")
       {return "correct"} else {return "done before functionParent()"
      }
}
</script>
```

edit2:  I've moved `this.$refs.childComponent.functionChild()` into the end of `functionParent()` which is not changing the result. It seems that calling function in child component is doing before child component gets the modified `resultArray`

Comment: Is `functionParent()` async? Then if it is async then obvoiusly `functionChild()` will start executing and will complete before async `functionParent()`

Comment: no, `functionParent()` is regular function, just copy objects etc...

Comment: Okay but I don't know deep(or thorough) about refs, but I can give one suggestion that instead of inline function, try defining it as a method which exposes `vm` to read refs as `this.$refs.childComponent.functionChild()` should work.

Comment: $refs are only populated after the component has been rendered, and they are not reactive. See this -https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

Comment: @MeetZaveri I added more details of my code

Comment: @MeetZaveri I see your point, but the $refs calling from parent component is making correct effect - they just execute the function

Comment: Okay after viewing edit,I want to know is `<btn>` in  child or parent?

Comment: @MeetZaveri in parent. I've moved `this.$refs.childComponent.functionChild()` into the end of `functionParent()` which is not changing the result. It seems that calling function in child component is doing before child component gets the modified `resultArray`

Comment: Ahaan! Good to detect this behaviour

Comment: @MeetZaveri great, what now? :)

Comment: Let me do experiment in codesandbox

Comment: Review this codesandbox .Just have a look at this - https://codesandbox.io/s/k1oq33qrqv

Comment: @MeetZaveri yes I see this is working correct. In my case  `<child-comp
:result-array="resultArray"
ref="childComponent"> 
</child-comp>` is in the next step of the side, so sending prop is delayed. I've found the solution and it is very primitive: `setTimeout(() => {this.$refs.childComponent.functionChild();}, 100)`
Ideally it would be if child component will send information to parent - "okay I recieved new prop" and after this - computed once run `functionChild()`

Comment: Good to know. Adjusting acc. to our pattern/scenario would make sense. So it's done now dude?

Comment: Add answer here to your own question so that people can acknowledge the solution.

Comment: @MeetZaveri yes, thank you, this is working now, but who knows when it will crash :)

Comment: @MeetZaveri I will not answer on this, because this is too primitive, and maybe someone will provide better answer (you may try)

Comment: Okay but if anyone doesn't respond here after days, you can add your primitive solution as only answer that SO will definitely accept

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue using promises. They are perfect for this.

Create yourself an onClick function in your component that your button will call.

Make the functionParent return a promise.

Then your onClick function will look a little like this....

```js
function onClick () {
  functionParent().then( () => {
    functionChild()
  })
}
```

Your function parent will look a bit like this...

```js
functionParent () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do your stuff ....
    resolve()
  })
}
```

Hope that helps.

You can find info on promises here..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Using a timeout is not a good option. There is no guarantee your functions will finish in the correct order

Comment: thanks for answer - this is best practice for functions order. However the problem seems to have other cause - both functions (doesn't matter if one is after another) execute before `resultArray` is send via props into child component. So you have the situation that events order is: 1. `functionParent()` 2. `funcionChild()` 3. sending updated `resultArray` to child component. Should be this way: 1. `functionParent()` 2. sending updated resultArray to child component.  3. `funcionChild()`. This is why promises don't work here, but timeout does...

Comment: Perhaps this is not the right architecture for this problem then. The vuex store is perhaps a better solution, or create a simple service that can share the data between the components. Relying on a timeout does not feel correct.

Comment: I fully agree. I will probably move into vuex, but now I still rely on simpler solution

Answer (score -1):

If anyone will have the same problem - this is very primitive solution that I invented thanks to @Meet Zaveri help:

just call `functionChild()` from `functionParent()` with time delay. In this case:

```
functionParent() {
  this.resultArray = "result"
  setTimeout(() => {this.$refs.childComponent.functionChild();}, 100)
}
```

This will give Vue time to send the updated `resultArray` into the child props

I know there could and should be a better solution to this, but if you have no other option or idea this is the easiest one.

If you have a better answer, just post it here and let me know!

Comment: Down-voted because trying to control flow via timeouts is extremely brittle.  What works on one machine/network/environment can behave totally differently on another machine/network/environment.

Comment: @PatrickSteele I respect your opinion, as I mentioned this is very primitive solution and should be avoided, but now I can't see better, so this is what I posted